# Unexpected Trace "AI (Internal): Operation to stop does not match the current operation"

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've got a simple DotNet Core 2.0 app using AppInsights. I've started using the AppInsights SDK to and the TrackTrace(). It's working fine, but queries on the traces table in AppInsights are showing a number of traces with a message of "AI (Internal): Operation to stop does not match the current operation". I'm not generating these and they are polluting my data. Any idea why they are generated and how I can make them stop?

Here are the trace details (with some values obscured):

```
timestamp [UTC]: 2018-01-10T19:39:20.651Z
message: AI (Internal): Operation to stop does not match the current operation.
operation_SyntheticSource: SDKTelemetry
client_Type: PC
client_IP: my-ip-address
client_CountryOrRegion: United States
appId: 43dda5df-4e1c-46a9-82ee-977811e262b5
appName: debug-fossil
iKey: my-ikey-value
sdkVersion: dotnet:2.4.0-32153
itemId: f754898b-f63d-11e7-8081-3b3156d2a6a2
itemType: trace
itemCount: 1
```

Comment: since this is more of a "problem" than a programming question, a better place would be to post this directly as an issue to the AI github: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet

Comment: in general though it looks like something changed the operation name or somehow the operation was disposed at some point which caused these comparisons to fail and log that message.

Comment: I've logged a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/693